# Sharepoint 2010 is returning corrupt html and image data

Tags: pages, support

I have an issue with several SharePoint 2010 installations that have "corrupt" HTML on their web pages (how to explain). It' like the site stops sending HTML data midway through the transfer of the HTML data. Images come out corrupt. HTML and images don't fully load in the browser. 
It's not the source files of the server.

If SharePoint runs out of memory on the web front end can it cause this problem? Can an out of memory exception in IIS cause SharePoint to terminate during the transfer of HTML and image data to the browser?

Comment: Do you have anything between your browser and SP? Do you use any proxy?

Comment: No proxies or any other devices. The client system is connected to the physical ethernetwork to which the server is connected.

Comment: Do you see anything "suspicious" in the ULS logs? Have you done any customizations?

Comment: IIS stopping midway could explain this, i'd expect a 500 server error though.

Comment: P.S could you check eventlogs etc. for outofmemoryexceptions?

Comment: Hum... so, trying to remote to the server I get a message from RDP that because of a error in the encryption, the session will now end. Doesn't sound good. Also there are a host of errors in the event viewer, but no out of memory ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symantec End Point Protection.

It seems that Symantec for Windows 2008 isn't all it's cracked up to be. People have been reporting problems with getting access to servers, bad data etc. While I'm not 100% positive that it's the problem, now that I have removed the software I am no longer experiencing the problems.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, the expected behaviour of SharePoint under memory stress is that page response times would increase dramatically as Windows tries to thrash memory pages to disk. Sending garbage back to the client is not what you would expect.

These problems suggest something wrong with the server, but you talk about having this problem with several installations, presumably on different hardware. Do you have custom code? What do these installations have in common? Do they share a database server? I'm afraid that there isn't enough information to start to narrow down what the problem might be.

Comment: Ok so to answer: No custom code. The only thing that they have in common is that they are on VMs. No shared database server. Some have 4gbs allocated and some have 6 (both web and database).

Comment: Are all the VMs running on the same physical machine?

Comment: They are running on the same physical machine.

Comment: In that case you must be running some third party antivirus product that is messing things up ;-)

Comment: Yep most likely.